# Populate State dropdown based on the selection of country dropdown in java spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, drop-down-menu, combobox

In my controller I have written as follows to populate country list and state list:

```
@ModelAttribute("countries")
public List<Country> initializeCountries() {

    List <Country> countries = countryService.findAllCountrys();

    return countries;
}
```

@ModelAttribute("states")
   public List initializeStates() {

```
List <State> states = stateService.findAllStates();

   return states;
```

}

And in my jsp, I have populated both country and state successfully:

```
<form:select path="country" id="country">
  <form:option value="">Select Country</form:option>
  <form:options items="${countries}" itemValue="countryCode" itemLabel 
     = "countryName" />
</form:select>
<form:errors path="country" cssClass="error"/>

<form:select path="state" id="state">
    <form:option value="">Select Country</form:option>
    <form:options items="${states}" itemValue="stateCode" 
  itemLabel="stateName" />
</form:select>
<form:errors path="state" cssClass="error"/>
```

But I need to populate state based on the selection of country.

Comment: you have to use javascript to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax and JavaScript/JQuery. Here giving an example, that may help you

```
$("#country").change(function() {
    var countryId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/fetchStates',
        data: {
            countryId : countryId,
        },
        error: function() { 
            alert("Error");
        },
        success: function(stateDetails) {
            // call a function to populate state details
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please check the below code and let me know your suggestions